# Search and Replace Content Between and Including Tags with Coda Editor

Tags: regex, coda, replace

I have document with a few hundred lines of code.  I'm using Coda to edit the file. I'm trying to replace the content with the [tibby] tags with a "space".  For example I would like to change the following:

`Some text before the tag [tippy title="Share the Knowledge"]Some content. http://twitter.com/home?status=subject" title="Tweet This"> Some other content.[/tippy] More text...`
 
with the following:

`Some text before the tag  More text...`
 
**Basically removing the [tippy] tags and all the content within the open and closing tags.**

Would someone be so kind as to tell me what I would enter in the search string.

Thanks

Comment: Could those tags be nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy:

```
 find: \[tippy[^]]*][^]]*\[/tippy]       or \[\/tippy]
 replace: a space
```

OR

```
 find: \[tiby[^\]]*\][^\]]\[/tippy\]    or \[\/typpy\] 
 replace: a space
```

Comment: @m.buettner: congratulieration for your bounty answer.

Comment: Thanks a million Casimir, I tried the first one and it works beautifully :)